# my yaml file raised a erorr,can any one help me out

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: mongo
   labels:
     run: mongo
spec:
   ports:
   – port: 27017
     targetPort: 27017
     protocol: TCP
   selector:
     run: mongo

—
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
   name: mongo
spec:
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         run: mongo
     spec:
       containers:
       – name: mongo
         image: mongo
         ports:
         – containerPort: 27017
```

Comment: Can you please add some [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)? And a description of the error you're seeing? Otherwise, we can't really help.

Comment: If you really have a single `-` between the service and the deployment, that's probably the reason. You need three dashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: mongo
  name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    run: mongo

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: mongo
  name: mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mongo
        name: mongo
```

I generated it using:

`kubectl run --image=mongo mongo  --dry-run -o yaml`

`kubectl expose deployment mongo --port=27017 --dry-run -o yaml`